# Where are panel applet information stored in mate?

Tags: panel, mate

I had an Ubuntu installation that no longer boots.
I had mate-panel. There were useful bits of code I wrote into the 
custom panel applets. Where is the information about custom application launchers stored inside of mate panel?

Comment: In what panel you had those links?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't in some .conf, .dconf, .mate directory?

Comment: Mate as the Mate Desktop Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I was referring to mate-desktop, and the panel applets, also called launchers.

The info I was looking for is in:

`~/.config/mate/panel2.d/default/launchers`